# AdMob Ads Not Loading on Android 4.0 & 4.1

Tags: android, admob

Using AdMob SDK v8.3.0 and ads are loading properly on newer versions of Android - all is working as expected.

However ads are not showing up for Android 4.0 & 4.1 devices.

On one 4.1 test device LogCat shows:

```
There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
```

On another 4.1 and 4.0 test devices there are no error messages at all. Seems like ads are silently failing.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: what does logcat say? (add a filter for "ads" to see the admob traces)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found a solution to my own problem.

For whatever reason I needed to Reset Advertising ID. Not sure why this had to be done, but just confirmed on 2 x Android 4.1 and 1 x Android 4.0 test devices.

**Android 4.1 Instructions:**

- Settings -> Accounts / Google -> Ads -> Reset Advertising ID

**Android 4.0 Instructions:**

- Apps -> Google Settings App -> Ads -> Reset Advertising ID

After this Ads are loading as expected.

Hope this helps someone experiencing similar issue. If anyone could explain why this occurred in the comments, it would be appreciated and add to understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the data of your Google play app and Service in Setting->app management, worked for me on android 4.1 samsung galaxy win